# Looping python function that Looks for USB in Windows 10

Tags: python

Ok, so I'm trying to make a python script that will look for a USB drive called `MyUSB`, and the program will check for it every 2 seconds. Does anyone have any suggested code I should use?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. To post here you should have made an attempt to solve your problem and you get help on the way. I suggest you start using Google first, I'd say it take most ppl less than 1 minute to find code snippets and start trying.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Project](https://github.com/ajphukan/monpendrive) in which i have used to check usb detection .

```
 import os
 a=os.popen("wmic logicaldisk get description")
 dev_list=a.read()
 if "Removable" in dev_list:
    print("Pendrive Detected")
 else:
    print("Pendrive is not there")
```

but it detects all removable drive .